# Repeatedly using $(document).ready(function () in a js file

Tags: jquery

I have a js file called "app.js" that I store most of my javascript in so that it can be easily minimized.

I noticed that I've been wrapping each of the unique functions in:

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

There are about 10 functions wrapped this way in the file. Would it better for me to instead wrap the entire app.js file inside of the $(document).ready instead of each individual function?

I feel like I might have read to avoid abusing the document, but I may just be thinking of $(this)?

Are there any performance problems in what I'm doing?

Comment: You can use it as many times as you like, it shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: No issue, they just execute in top-to-bottom fashion.

Comment: Every call is adding the declaration to an execution queue (which needs to be stored somewhere). Though nominal, there is probably a slightly higher amount of resources being used. However, unless you're noticing performance issues I wouldn't touch it. "If it ain't broke..."

Comment: should put them all under one umbrella. but the way you are doing it will not harm anything

Comment: JQuery events are subscription based. Each `ready` function adds a function to the ready event's function list. When the event is triggered all functions in the list are invoked in order. All jQuery events work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any performance issues with this kind of approach, but in my opinion it looks ugly and hard to read.

What i suggest is to use just one `ready` function to act as your `init` and then store functions outside `ready`, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

//check some stuff once document is ready
check_if_user_is_loggedin();

//check if user got new message
setInterval(function(){
   check_user_inbox();
}, 5000);

});


//now here store your functions like:
function check_if_user_is_loggedin(){
  if(loggedIn) return true; else return false;
}

check_user_inbox(){
  //ajax call etc...
  return messages;
}
```